# 'yield from' inside async function Python 3.6.5 aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.6, aiohttp, yield-from

SyntaxError: 'yield from' inside async function

```
async def handle(request):
    for m in (yield from request.post()):
        print(m)
    return web.Response()
```

Used python3.5 before, found pep525, install python3.6.5 and still receive this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the new `async`/`await` syntax to define and execute co-routines, but have not made a full switch. You need to use `await` here:

```
async def handle(request):
    post_data = await request.post()
    for m in post_data:
        print(m)
    return web.Response()
```

If you wanted to stick to the old, pre-Python 3.5 syntax, then mark your function as a coroutine with the [`@asyncio.coroutine` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine), drop the `async` keyword, and use `yield from` instead of `await`:

```
@async.coroutine
def handle(request):
    post_data = yield from request.post()
    for m in post_data:
        print(m)
    return web.Response()
```

but this syntax is being phased out, and is not nearly as discoverable and readable as the new syntax. You should only use this form if you need to write code that is compatible with older Python versions.